# Tuner Studio MS Installation

Tags: software-installation

I'm very new to Linux. I installed in two lap top so far. in the second one I'm trying to run an app that requires Java, I don't know haw to make the run in Ubuntu 16.04. the app that I want to run is Tuner Studio ms for Linux. I have downloaded both of them and extracted them, thats all I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Tunerstudio has a guide on installation on Ubuntu here: [User Contributed How To Videos | tunerstudio.com](http://tunerstudio.com/index.php/uservideos)

Comment: Thanks so much. the video did not help that much, I found out that I had to install java, I did so asking how to install it in google, and I succeeded.